# derivatives transformation

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, partial-derivative, general-relativity

I'm currently doing a calculation for the connection coefficients using the standard space-time coordinates, namely $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3$. The setup is a spherically symmetric problem.

In my expressions, I have derivatives with respect to these functions (i.e. $d/dx_0,d/dx_1$ etc). Now I am trying to rewrite my results in terms of spherical coordinates $t,r$ (no $\theta$ and $\phi$ because of spherical symmetry), with $r=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$ and need to replace the $x$'s derivatives with the spherical ones.

That is where my problem is. The usual transformation from cartesian to spherical derivatives involves coefficients that depend on $\theta$ and $\phi$. But I don't have those to start with!

So, my question is, how do I find the derivatives w.r.t. $x$'s in terms of spherical coords for the *spherically symmetric* case?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: so in your  case you have $3D$ or $4D$  ?

Comment: So you have partial derivatives in cartesian coordinates and want to get partial derivatives in spherical ones? Seems your problem is in fact $3D$. If it's $4D$, then how is your 4th coordinate transformed?

Comment: sorry for the omission! Yes, it is 3D. That is, my x[0] is t. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to rewrite derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ in terms of spherical coordinates $r, \theta, \phi$. They are gonna be not as nice as you might think based on spherical symmetry. These derivatives rather reflect how $f$ looks in cartesian coordinates, and in general they *will* depend on all of $r,\theta$ and $\phi$ when transformed to spherical coords.
You might want to see instead how del ($\nabla$) or Laplacian ($\nabla^2$) look in spherical coordinates. Expressions for them acting on spherically-symmetric function will be then indeed independent of $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Comment: All right, so Laplacian in spherical coordinates is $\Delta=\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{2}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^{2}\sin^{2}\phi}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\theta^{2}}+\frac{\cos\phi}{r^{2}\sin\phi}\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}+\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\phi^{2}}$. If I "discard" the last three summands due to spherical symmetry, I'm only left with the first two terms which do not involve the angles. But still do not see how I go from there to get my *first* order derivatives, i.e. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}$ for i=1,2,3

Comment: I mean, in my calculation only the first order derivatives appear, so I cannot directly make use of Laplacian.

Comment: First order derivatives will be in del (nabla $\nabla$) operator. But I'm not sure you'll get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ from $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ looking as you seem to want.

Comment: well, the nabla operator is $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}+\phi\mathrm{term}$. However, what I got so far, by simply using the chain rule, is that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}=\frac{x_{i}}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ (I hope this is correct). The problem being, therefore, those $x_{i}$ to the first order. So from what I understand, you're saying there is no way of getting those derivatives straight?

Comment: Yes, you can't have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=\xi(r)$. You'll have instead $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=\zeta(r,\theta,\phi)$.

Answer (score 1):

When $\theta=0$ at the equator you have
$$r=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2},\quad \phi={\rm arg}(x_1,x_2),\quad \theta={\rm arg}\bigl(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2},x_3\bigr)\ .$$
For a function $f:{\mathbb R}^3\to{\mathbb R}$ that does not depend on $\phi$ or $\theta$ we therefore obtain using  the chain rule:
$${\partial f\over\partial x_i}={\partial f\over\partial r}{\partial r\over\partial x_i}+ {\partial f\over\partial \phi}{\partial \phi\over\partial x_i}+{\partial f\over\partial \theta}{\partial \theta\over\partial x_i} ={\partial f\over\partial r}{x_i\over r}+0+0\ .\tag{1}$$
A coordinate-free version of $(1)$ is the following: Dentote by $r\mapsto \tilde f(r)$ the underlying function of $r$ alone. For a given point $p\in{\mathbb R}^3$ and a "displacement vector" $X\in T_p$ one then has
$$df(p).X=\nabla f(p)\cdot X=\tilde f'(|p|){X\cdot p\over|p|}\ .$$

Comment: well, I also got $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}=\frac{x_{i}}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ using the chain rule. However, my problem was, that I don't even have the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ introduced in my spherically symmetric problem. That is, I cannot simply write down $\cos$ or $\sin$ of non-existent coordinates. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @user2206544 You'll have to tell more about your problem for us to see if you're missing something.